# how to auto generate Universal Angular files?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I follow the tutorial from angular for Universal:
https://angular.io/guide/universal

I try to install Universal with:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject angular.io-example
```

Well, the code running fine doesn't return any error. But it doesn't generate any of following files like it suppose to:

```
main.server.ts
tsconfig.server.json      
app.server.module.ts    
server.ts                    
webpack.server.config.js
```

Here is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-io-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Example project from an angular.io guide.",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "ng": "ng"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^7.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "github:brandonroberts/in-memory-web-api-bazel#50a34d8",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.4",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

So, is the documentation missing something? or am I missing something?

Comment: It's definitely a problem with dependencies because I have tried it first on my project with my dependencies and it worked, then I tried it with your dependencies and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

After few tries I tried to update some dependencies the problem here is located in the typescript version. Change it from `typescript: '^3.1.1'` to `typescript: '^3.2.2'`. Then this command should work properly.

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject angular.io-example
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it does solve the problem, I just don't understand, the tutorial come from the official site, why do they have this error? Also could you explain the error here :-?

Comment: I am not sure what caused this. Maybe there is some problem with compatibility or just some bug.